# Does the sequence length of a RNN/LSTM have to be the same for the input and output?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a question about the input and output data in a RNN or LSTM. A RNN expects a 3-dimensional vector as input of the form (Batch_size, sequence_length_input, features_input) and a 3-dimensional output vector of the form (Batch_size, sequence_length_output, features_output).

I know that the features_input and features_output don't have to have the same number. But what about the middle part sequence_length_input and sequence_length_output. Do they have to be the same? At least in my example (with Keras and Tensorflow) I always get an error if they are not the same. So I am wondering whetever I have a bug in the code or if this is generally not possible.

**Update**: Here is my code with a RNN for time series forecasting that only works if the sequence_length of the input `steps_backward` is equal to the sequence_length of the output `steps_forward` otherwise it will throw a ValueError:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 192 and 96 for '{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](sequential_5/time_distributed_5/Reshape_1, IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [?,192,1], [?,96,1].
```

In the code I use the 96 past timesteps (or 2*96=192 timesteps) to predict the future 96 timesteps. When the number of past and future timesteps are equal (equal sequence_length), everything works fine. Otherwise (unequal sequence_length) I get the ValueError.

```
#Import modules
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from tensorflow import keras

# Define the parameters of the RNN and the training
epochs = 1
batch_size = 50
steps_backwards = 2 * 96
steps_forward = 96
split_fraction_trainingData = 0.70
split_fraction_validatinData = 0.90
randomSeedNumber = 50

#Read dataset
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/User1/Desktop/TestData.csv', sep=';', header=0, low_memory=False, infer_datetime_format=True, parse_dates={'datetime':[0]}, index_col=['datetime'])

# standardize data

data = df.values
indexWithYLabelsInData = 0
data_X = data[:, 0:3]
data_Y = data[:, indexWithYLabelsInData].reshape(-1, 1)


scaler_standardized_X = StandardScaler()
data_X = scaler_standardized_X.fit_transform(data_X)
data_X = pd.DataFrame(data_X)
scaler_standardized_Y = StandardScaler()
data_Y = scaler_standardized_Y.fit_transform(data_Y)
data_Y = pd.DataFrame(data_Y)


# Prepare the input data for the RNN

series_reshaped_X =  np.array([data_X[i:i + (steps_backwards+steps_forward)].copy() for i in range(len(data) - (steps_backwards+steps_forward))])
series_reshaped_Y =  np.array([data_Y[i:i + (steps_backwards+steps_forward)].copy() for i in range(len(data) - (steps_backwards+steps_forward))])


timeslot_x_train_end = int(len(series_reshaped_X)* split_fraction_trainingData)
timeslot_x_valid_end = int(len(series_reshaped_X)* split_fraction_validatinData)

X_train = series_reshaped_X[:timeslot_x_train_end, :steps_backwards] 
X_valid = series_reshaped_X[timeslot_x_train_end:timeslot_x_valid_end, :steps_backwards] 
X_test = series_reshaped_X[timeslot_x_valid_end:, :steps_backwards] 

   
Y_train = series_reshaped_Y[:timeslot_x_train_end, steps_backwards:] 
Y_valid = series_reshaped_Y[timeslot_x_train_end:timeslot_x_valid_end, steps_backwards:] 
Y_test = series_reshaped_Y[timeslot_x_valid_end:, steps_backwards:]                                
   
   
# Build the model and train it

np.random.seed(randomSeedNumber)
tf.random.set_seed(randomSeedNumber)

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(10, return_sequences=True, input_shape=[None, 3]),
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(10, return_sequences=True),
    keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(1))
])

model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="adam")
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(X_valid, Y_valid))

#Predict the test data
Y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

and here is some test data https://filetransfer.io/data-package/ufbzh09o#link

**Reminder**: The code and the data provide a Minimal reproducible example. Maybe you can have a look at it as in this code the sequence_length has to be equal for the input and output data, otherwise I get an error. Unfortuantely I still have not figured out why this this problem occurs

Comment: Can you post an example of your code so that we understand what you are trying to solve?

Generally, only older machine translation models required same length for input and output.

Comment: @hH1sG0n3: Thanks for your comment. My question was more a general question whether it is possible to have different sequence_lengths for LSTMs regarding the input and output data. So can I for example use as input for the training, the data X_train =(1000, 100, 10) and the output Y_train = (1000, 20, 3) such that I have a mapping for each of the 1000 itmes (Batch_size) from a 10-dimensional (features_input) time series with 100 time steps (sequence_length_input) to a 3-dimensional (features_output) time series with 20 time steps (sequence_length_output).

Comment: @hH1sG0n3: Any comment to my last comment? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: The answer is no they dont have to be the same and in fact can be any length. Recurrent neural networks are `recurrent` after all. The same cell is used for the forward pass each time.  $$h_t = f_w(h_{t-1},x_t)$$  You can reuse $h_t$ again and again forever!

Comment: @GaryOng: Thanks for your answer Gary. Can you then tell me why I get the error mentioned above when using my code? When the sequence lengths of input and output are the same, everything is fine. If they are different, I get a value error telling me that the dimensionality does not match

Comment: When return sequences is set to true it will return the output for all 96*2 time steps.  So you need to modify your keras code to only take the mse of the last 96 timesteps and only do the backpropagation from there. I dont think the sequential api allows for this modification. See here for more info https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers

Comment: @GaryOng: Thanks Gary for your answer and effort. Actually I am a bit confused. You said that LSTM/RNN can map different sequence sizes to each other if I understood correctly. Now I am just trying to do this and I get a value error. So the model should map each of the 2*96 values (with 3 dimensions) to the 96 label values (with 1 dimension), such that after training the model should use 2*96 values (with 3 dimensions) per batch item in the test dataset to predict 1*96 values (with 1 dimension). I don't understand why I get an error altough LSTM/RNN should be able to do this as you wrote.

Comment: @GaryOng: Thanks for your answer Gary. Any comments to my last comment? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you

Comment: @hH1sG0n3: I posted an example of my code as you demanded. Would you mind having a look at it and telling me why I always get an error when the sequence lengths are not the same?

Comment: @GaryOng: Any comments to my last comments?